# Can someone clarify how gamewon object is an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am confused on board.reduce((a, e, i). So far I was doing four loops inside loop to check if anybody has own in my tic-tac-toe game. But this function looks very small and hard to understand. Can some one clarify on that: checkwin() function. Also, is the object return gameWon a object of type Array. Also, how does this statement works: for (let index of winCombos[gameWon.index]) {

Objects value: squareID is one of {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, }
player is either A or B
board is array of [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7, 8]

```
function turn(squareId, player) {
  origBoard[squareId] = player;
  document.getElementById(squareId).innerHTML = player;
  let gameWon = checkWin(origBoard, player);
  if (gameWon) gameOver(gameWon);
  checkTie();
}

function checkWin(board, player) {
  let plays = board.reduce((a, e, i) => (e === player) ? a.concat(i) : a, []);
  let gameWon = null;
  for (let [index, win] of winCombos.entries()) {
    if (win.every(elem => plays.indexOf(elem) > -1)) {
      gameWon = {index: index, player: player};
      break;
    }
  }
  return gameWon;
}

function gameOver(gameWon){
  for (let index of winCombos[gameWon.index]) {
    document.getElementById(index).style.backgroundColor = 
      gameWon.player === huPlayer ? "blue" : "red";
  }
  for (let i=0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].removeEventListener('click', turnClick, false);
  }
  declareWinner(gameWon.player === huPlayer ? "You win!" : "You lose");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (let [index, win] of winCombos.entries()) {
if (win.every(elem => plays.indexOf(elem) > -1)) {
  gameWon = {index: index, player: player};
  break;
}
```

Iam having some trouble understanding this part especially the part with the if condition

Comment: this should be the comment and this is not an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
let plays = board.reduce((a, e, i) => (e === player) ? a.concat(i) : a, [])
```

Is the same as

```
let results = [];

for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
  const e = board[i];
  if (e === player) {
    results = results.concat(i);
  }
}

let plays = result;
```

Reduce takes an array and applies a function to each element to give a result, here is the same reduce with better variable names

```
board.reduce((result, item, index) => (item === player) ? result.concat(index) : result, [])
```

[] is the empty starting result array, result is the result from the previous iteration, item is the current item in the array and index is the items current index in the array. Each iteration we either return the result or we concat it if the current is the player.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same function with some names changed and whitespace added for readability:

```
function checkWin(board, playerSymbol) {
  let plays = board.reduce((accumulator, position, index) => {
    if (position === playerSymbol) { // i.e. the X or O player claimed the square
      return accumulator.concat(index);
    }
    return accumulator;
  }, []);

  let gameWon = null;
  for (let [index, win] of winCombos.entries()) {
    if (win.every(elem => plays.indexOf(elem) > -1)) {
      gameWon = {index: index, player: player};
      break;
    }
  }
  return gameWon;
}
```

The key insight here is that you are thinking of the board as 2-dimensional. But it doesn't have to be: you can represent the 3x3 grid as an array of length 9 and do `index % 3` to get the row. Much, much faster than nested loops.

So the `plays` variable is just an array length 9 representing the 3x3 board, and the reduce creates an array with every square claimed by the player. It then checks against a list of known winning combinations (e.g. [1,2,3], [1,5,9], [3,5,7]...) to see if the player won the game.

Comment: for (let index of winCombos[gameWon.index]) {

How is this one iterating?

Comment: @RochakKunwar the `.entries` method returns an [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators), and the [`for..of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) goes over them.